# My macro wont run if linked worksheet is protected

Tags: vba, excel

The purpose of this macro is to check that a username and password on the front sheet matches that of the password subscribed to a specif person to see if it matches, it then plants the username and password on the "Staff Salaries" sheet indefinitely.

The trouble im having is to stop someone changing the username and password that's been planted I lock the cells as the sheet is protected anyway, this seems to stop the macro working as it says it cannot change the cells if they are locked.

Is there an alternative i could use to prevent the clash?

```
Sub PASSWORD_CHECK()

Application.Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B24").Formula = ("=VLOOKUP(D4,Lock!R:T,1,FALSE)")     ' looks up school name
Application.Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B25").Formula = ("=EXACT(B24, D4)")                   ' validation of school name
Application.Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B26").Formula = ("=VLOOKUP(D4,Lock!R3:T106,3,FALSE)") ' looks up password
Application.Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B27").Formula = ("=EXACT(B26,D6)")                    ' validates password
Application.Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B29").Formula = ("=IF(AND(B25,B27),1,0)")             ' checks to validate both school and pasword
Application.Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B32").Formula = ("=IF(B27=B25,1,0)") ' Checks to see if password belongs to school


 Dim A As String
 Dim B As String
 Dim C As Boolean
 Dim D As String
 Dim E As String
 Dim F As Boolean

    A = Worksheets("Staff Salaries").Range("P3")
    B = Worksheets("Staff Salaries").Range("N2")
    C = Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B29")
    D = Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("D4")
    E = Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("D6")
    F = Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B32")

 If C = "TRUE" And F = "TRUE" Then                   ' All OK

        Worksheets("Staff Salaries").Range("N2") = D
        Worksheets("Staff Salaries").Range("P3") = E
    Else
                       MsgBox ("PASSWORD IS INCONSISTANT WITH USER")
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Simply Unprotect the sheet in the beginning of the code, and then protect it again in the end.
That said, VBA and Excel aren't very secure, and anyone with any knowledge of VBA can access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Sub PASSWORD_CHECK()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change the name of the sheet which is locked
    ws.Unprotect Password:="YourPassWord" ' Type your password

    Application.Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B24").Formula = ("=VLOOKUP(D4,Lock!R:T,1,FALSE)")     ' looks up school name
    Application.Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B25").Formula = ("=EXACT(B24, D4)")                   ' validation of school name
    Application.Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B26").Formula = ("=VLOOKUP(D4,Lock!R3:T106,3,FALSE)") ' looks up password
    Application.Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B27").Formula = ("=EXACT(B26,D6)")                    ' validates password
    Application.Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B29").Formula = ("=IF(AND(B25,B27),1,0)")             ' checks to validate both school and pasword
    Application.Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B32").Formula = ("=IF(B27=B25,1,0)") ' Checks to see if password belongs to school


     Dim A As String
     Dim B As String
     Dim C As Boolean
     Dim D As String
     Dim E As String
     Dim F As Boolean

        A = Worksheets("Staff Salaries").Range("P3")
        B = Worksheets("Staff Salaries").Range("N2")
        C = Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B29")
        D = Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("D4")
        E = Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("D6")
        F = Worksheets("Front sheet").Range("B32")

     If C = "TRUE" And F = "TRUE" Then                   ' All OK

            Worksheets("Staff Salaries").Range("N2") = D
            Worksheets("Staff Salaries").Range("P3") = E
        Else
                           MsgBox ("PASSWORD IS INCONSISTANT WITH USER")
    End If

   ws.Protect Password:="YourPassWord"  

    End Sub
```